# Get iPad Landscape Orientation in iOS5 at startup

Tags: ipad, ios5, uiinterfaceorientation, viewdidload

I've got an iPad App with a TabBarController. Since iOS5 I'm note able anymore to get the correct orientation in the viedDidLoad or viewWillAppear when I start the app on the iPad in landscape. It always returns Portrait. When I ask for the orientation in viewDidAppear, everything is fine and correct. In iOS4 I was able to get the right orientation, but now I build for iOS5 ... not anymore.

Please. What can I do to get the right orientation on the iPad on startup?

This is how I get my orientation:

```
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading any viewcontroller before loading RootViewContoller then Orientation of RootViewController needs to be set before adding it to window. you may find answer  [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738462/uisplitviewcontroller-and-orientation-ios-5-0/10620672#10620672)