# ios 6 orientation methods

Tags: iphone, ios6

the orientation methods have changed in iOS 6.
my whole app in portrait mode got to many view controllers (not tab bar view controllers) i just want to rotate one of my view controller to landscape mode (it actually displays a webView) when i rotate the device.the below method was working in xcode 4.4 but, it's not in Xcode.4.5

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
  (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
 interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || 
interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight );
```

the above method won't work in xcode 4.5 for this reason i have changed the below method but even though its not working....plz any suggestions thanks.

```
 - (BOOL) shouldAutorotate{
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:           UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
  return self.modalViewController.shouldAutorotate;
}
 -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Comment: The rotation code you've shown for rotation is not the same for iOS 5 and iOS 6. Have a look at `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown`.

Comment: check here it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738462/uisplitviewcontroller-and-orientation-ios-5-0/10620672#10620672

Comment: xcode is just an IDE an wether you use 4.4 or 4.5 of the IDE isnt important. Maybe you switch target sdk?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use tab bar view controller? If you use it, then all view controllers in all tabs should be able to rotate even if you only want to rotate only one.

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

This should work fine in iOS6.

---

If you use UINavigationViewController, then its methods would be called. There is another solution.

```
// App delegate.m
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application    supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    NSUInteger orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;

    if(self.window.rootViewController){
        UIViewController *presentedViewController = [[(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController viewControllers] lastObject];
        orientations = [presentedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }

    return orientations;
}
```

And then in view controllers

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: Guess you are using UINavigationController then, same situation: its shouldAutorotate & supportedInterfaceOrientations methods would be called. I've updated my answer with code excerpt, the other solution is to subclass UINavigationViewController. Basically you need to make application call methods of view controllers, not the wrapping view controller.

Comment: HI Dig  firstly thanks for your reply. yes i am using UINavigationController in my app delegate i added the code which you given me after the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions  method and also the another  NSUIntegersupportedInterfaceOrientations placed in the view controller which i need to rotate to landscape.but this is not working at all.i tried with another way which is actually i was got the code in app delegate isself.window addSubview:navigationController.view; i changed this one to window.rootViewController = navigationController now its rotating the whole app.but i need one app

Comment: @ShivaVattem Difficult to say without seeing project, maybe you could create minimal example of your case and upload it to github?